# Can anyone help me understand how MPI Communicator, Groups partitioning works?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

Can anyone help me get my head around the MPI Groups, Inter and Intra communicators. I have already gone through the MPI documentation(http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf   )  and I couldnt make good sense of these concepts. I would especially appreciate any code in the area of Inter communicators and communicator partitioning into groups within one communicator e.g. (MPI_COMM_WORLD)  this is because I think I can also learn by experimenting on live code .

Answer (score 2):

Can you expand upon what specifically doesn't make sense to you?

Generally speaking, however, I can say this: An MPI group is a set of processes. An MPI communicator is a way of talking between processes. If the communication is within a single group, then you are using an intracommunicator. If the communication is between two disjoing groups, then you're using an intercommunicator.

While you generally think of a communicator as spanning processes, each communicator is actually unique to a process. A communicator can be thought of as a handle to an object (group attribute) that describes a group of processes.

Comment: Thanks, let me just re-word and post.  For a start, I would basically appreciate a demonstration of how in code can one split a communicator like MPI_COMM_WORLD into MPI_Groups. For example, given a shape e.g. square, the program splits MPI_COMM_WORLD into two groups grpArea and grpPerimeter which compute the area and perimeter of the given shape. These groups should do their private computations and return result to root(rank 0) of MPI_COMM_WORLD. This  may noy be the best example but it illustrate where am stuck.