# MPI Reduce in 2 different groups

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am trying to do the following with the help of MPI_reduce and MPI_groups. I have created 2 different groups, one having the odd rank processes and another having the even rank processes, but in the new groups they are all numbered from 0 to N. What I am doing is that I am reducing all the values in group 1 and 2 using MPI_SUM. Say group 1 has the following values like-> 1,2,3 and group 2 has the following values say--> 4,5,6 then after reducing in group 1 I am getting 6 and in group2 I am getting 15, I am storing them respectively in recv_val1 and recv_val2. Now what I want to do is that I want to add them together, but whenever I do so, I get some garbage values. Why is this happening?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int myrank, size;

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank );
  MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size );

  int color = myrank%2;
  int newrank, newsize;

  int sendval, maxval,recv_val1,recv_val2;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Comm newcomm;
  MPI_Comm_split (MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, myrank, &newcomm);


  MPI_Comm_rank( newcomm, &newrank );
  MPI_Comm_size( newcomm, &newsize );

  //printf("color and newrank are %d and %d \n", color, newrank);  
  sendval = newrank;

  if(color==0)
  MPI_Reduce(&sendval, &recv_val1, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, newcomm); // find sum
  else
  MPI_Reduce(&sendval, &recv_val2, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, newcomm); // find sum


  if(newrank == 0 && color == 0)
  printf("%d\n",  recv_val1);
  if(newrank == 0 && color == 1)
  printf("%d\n", recv_val2);

  if(myrank==0)
  printf(" sum is %d\n", recv_val1+recv_val2);

  MPI_Comm_free(&newcomm);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not use `MPI_Group` but use `MPI_Comm_split()` to create communicators with even and odd ranks. Then `MPI_Reduce()` on the generated communicator. What you are missing is `recv_val1` is only on rank `0` of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and `recv_val2` is only on rank `1` of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, so you need to send/recv one of these variables in order to be able to sum both on a given rank.

Comment: How can I send/recv from one communicator to another? Is there any way to do so?

Comment: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367479/mpi-communicator-mpi-comm-split-without-groups" this link says that there is no point of using splits without groups

Comment: you cannot directly send from one communicator to an other, but you do not have to since both tasks all belong to `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. I think you misread the link (e.g. group as a concept vs `MPI_Group`.

Comment: I have updated the code using MPI_comm_split. Can you please tell me where it is wrong now, that I am not getting the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: as I wrote earlier, `myrank==1` must send `recv_val2` to `myrank==0` (that must receive it)